# How to add two arrays in C++ from two separate for loops

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I am reasonably new to programming and I was wondering how I would add arrays 'adv' and 'rcd' together. I'm assuming that the issue is because of arrays 'adv' and 'rcd' are only recognised inside the respective 'for' loops. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <new>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <vector>

    const double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    const double convToRad = pi/180.0;
    int index1 = 180;
    int index2 = 0;
    int index3 = 0;
    int o, u, w;

    int main(){

    double rcd[index1];

    for (int o = index1; o >= 90; o--){

      rcd[o] = o*convToRad;
      //std::cout << rcd[o] << std::endl;
 }

 double adv[index2];

 for (int u = index2; u <= 90; u++){

    adv[u] = u*convToRad;
    //std::cout << adv[u] << std::endl;
 }

double car[index3];

for (int w = index3; w <= 90; w++){

    car[w] = (adv[u]+rcd[o])/2;
    std::cout << car[w] << std::endl;
  }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You've declared `double car[index3]` when index3 is zero.

Answer (score 1):

You've attempted to declare the array `double car[index3]` when `index3` was set to zero, in other words, the array `car[index3]` is defined as: `car[0]`. Same with `double adv[index2]`.

---

**A correct example to do so:**

```
#include <iostream>

const int MAX = 10;

int main(void) {
    double arr1[MAX]   {0};
    double arr2[MAX]   {0};
    double arrSum[MAX] {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        // example
        arr1[i] = i + 4;
        // std::cout << arr1[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        // example
        arr2[i] = i + 1;
        // std::cout << arr2[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        arrSum[i] = (arr1[i] + arr2[i]) / 2;
        std::cout << arrSum[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that it doesn't solves your exact problem since I only given a code which does the work you want, but yes, it'll guide you how to solve it correctly.

---

**Sample Output:**

```
2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5 10.5 11.5
// sum of arr1[1] + arr2[1] <space> arr1[2] + arr2[2] ...
// uncomment the cout syntax to see further output
```

Comment: Thanks that helps. I have also noticed that 'adv' for loop does not print anything. Would you know what I would need to change to get it to print, I've tried messing around with it but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @pies84 try to change the value of `index2`, and `index3`, since both are initialized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple errors.

```
int index1 = 180;
int index2 = 0;
int index3 = 0;
```

When you are initializing arrays rcd is made of size 180, where as adv is of size 0.

```
for (int w = index3; w <= 90; w++){

    car[w] = (adv[u]+rcd[o])/2;
    std::cout << car[w] << std::endl;
}
```

In the loop values of u and o are constant.